# How to make openvpn client use specific internet connection?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

my remote raspberry pi is connected to 2 different sources of internet.
One over eth01 (home network) and second over wlan01 (private owned by me) .

I want to know how can I make openvpn client use wlan01 only?

Thank you